# Looping through a HTML list

Tags: javascript, html, foreach

I would like to have a piece of JS which loops through a list-item series and for each list-item, it stores a unique attribute value (in this case, the href) and then inserts it as a data attribute to another element within the same list-item (in this case, the button). The JS which I have only applies the desired effect to the first list-item and not the whole series. Can my method be tweaked, or does it require surgery?

```
<li class="productgrid--item">
  <a class="productitem--image-link" href="www.link_one.com">link one</a>
  <button class="atc-button--text">button one</button>
</li>
<li class="productgrid--item">
  <a class="productitem--image-link" href="www.link_two.com">link two</a>
  <button class="atc-button--text">button two</button>
</li>
<li class="productgrid--item">
  <a class="productitem--image-link" href="www.link_three.com">link three</a>
  <button class="atc-button--text">button three</button>
</li>
```

```
document.querySelectorAll('.productgrid--item').forEach(function(node) {
  var anchorHref = document.querySelector('.productitem--image-link').getAttribute('href');
  var addToCart = document.querySelector('.atc-button--text');
  addToCart.setAttribute('data', anchorHref);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `forEach()` you should use `node.querySelector()` instead of `document.querySelector()`.

See https://jsfiddle.net/qkd37rsu/

`document.querySelector()` selects within entire document tree and returns the first matching element while `node.querySelector()` searches only subtree of `node` element (and returns the first matching element). Note that `node` is just a parameter provided by `forEach(function(node){...})`.

Answer (score 0):

it's easier to follow if you work with your foreach node and from there get and set the attributes you want

```js
  document.querySelectorAll('.productgrid--item').forEach(function(node) {
  var anchorHref = node.querySelector('.productitem--image-link').getAttribute('href');
  var addToCart = node.querySelector('.atc-button--text');
  addToCart.setAttribute('data', anchorHref);
  console.log(addToCart)
});
```

```html
<li id='a' class="productgrid--item">
  <a id='a1' class="productitem--image-link" href="www.link_one.com">link one</a>
  <button class="atc-button--text">button one</button>
</li>
<li id='b' class="productgrid--item">
  <a class="productitem--image-link" href="www.link_two.com">link two</a>
  <button class="atc-button--text">button two</button>
</li>
<li id='c' class="productgrid--item">
  <a class="productitem--image-link" href="www.link_three.com">link three</a>
  <button class="atc-button--text">button three</button>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, many thanks - I had no idea about this node business. I presume it means something like 'this' in the jQuery form...kinda. I'm still learning, but this node thing will help me practice lots and get better. Thank you.